# A small window opens for a seccond

Tags: macos, high-sierra

Everytime I start the Macbook, a small window opens for a seccond and disapeared. I managed to take a screenshot for that provided below,

[image]

I have High Sierra OS instilled and the machine config is provided below,

[image]

This started from today though this doesnt creates any other issue. However, I'm worried that this may be the symptom of something bigger that would come later point.

Does anyone see this before or can explain?

Comment: OS X is not doing that, it is one of your apps

Comment: This is great to know. Do you if I can find out which app is creating this issue? It’s not continuing and only momentary though

Comment: I have no idea how other then closing all you apps and opening one by one and monitoring.

Comment: This must be one of the apps that starts automatically with login. We may use process of elimination from there.

Comment: This helps me to know that this is not from OS X. Please, write it as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen the OS X doing that ever.

It must be one of your Applications.

The OS X is already fully up and running at the time that Window pops up.